# How do I clone an object from detecting characters in a string in unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I've created a new project to test scripts based on the topics I write. to apply to real projects. But I don't know how to do it...

I have an object called Pad, it is Prefab, and I want it to be cloned according to the string below.

```
string levelI = "0000000" +
    "0000000" +
    "0111110" +
    "0111110" +
    "0111110" +
    "0111110" +
    "0011100" +
    "0010100" +
    "0010100" +
    "0011100" +
    "0011100";
```

//Oh, another requirement is how to extract strings from other files

to be in this format after game start

[image: picture is here]

Ah yes, a game page like this looks like a certain game. But this is just an example of what I would like to do from an actual project...

Comment: Surely this is a design thing so the storing as a thing you had already worked out how you would decipher it rather than randomly make a string and am the world to work out what you would do. What specifically are you stuck on?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You want an array of 11 rows and 7 columns so you input should be

```
      string[] levelI = {
            "0000000",
            "0000000",
            "0111110",
            "0111110",
            "0111110",
            "0111110",
            "0011100",
            "0010100",
            "0010100",
            "0011100",
            "0011100"
        };
        foreach(string row in levelI)
        {
            //add row new row of buttons
            for(int col = 0; col < 7; col++)
            {
                char digit = row[col];

            }
        }
```

Comment: Oh thanks for this, but do you know how to detect the number 1 and continue working? I don't know and don't have time to find an answer to this

Comment: thank you very much!!! I can now continue the project

Comment: When reading from a file each row will be on a new line.